# How to check which id is visible on screen while the user is scrolling? Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to get some information of what is really visible on the screen to the user. The main idea is, while he scrolls down, i need to get info of in which part of the category list he is.

I'm trying to do this way:

```
 <div [ngClass]="navFixed ? 'sticky' : ''" >
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="row">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let category of NavigationCategories">
            <button type="button" 
            (click)="NavegateToCategory(category)"
            [ngClass]="trim(selectedTab) == trim(category) ? 
            'btn btn-danger': 
            'btn btn-outline-danger'" 
            class="btn btn-outline-danger "
            rippleEffect >{{category}}</button>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<ng-container  *ngFor="let category of data | filter: searchTxt; let i = index " >
    <div #category [id]="trim(category.category)" class="row text-center" [attr.data-index]="i" style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="card" 
        style="
        padding: 1rem;
        ">
        <h4 style="margin-top: auto;
         margin-bottom: auto;"><strong>{{category.category}}</strong></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

on ts:

```
@ViewChild('category') category: QueryList<ElementRef>

  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  onWindowScroll() {
   console.log(this.category)
    
    this.navFixed = (window.pageYOffset 
      || document.documentElement.scrollTop 
      || document.body.scrollTop || 0
    ) > this.scrollOffset; 

  }

 trim(str:string){
    return str.replaceAll(' ', '')
  }
```

on console.log:

```
ElementRef {nativeElement: div#category1.row.text-center}
```

Inside the "onWindowScroll()", i need to modify a variable that contains the dynamic Id of the loop, and i'm storing it inside a var called selectTab. For example the user is on the first category, the moment that he switches to the next one, i need to receive a string of the category that has been displayed to him. this way, i should be able to modify the view. The real problem is: The viewChild only shows the first item of the ngfor Loop, even when i switch to another one, the value is the same.

I tryed using the ViewChildren as well, no success.. but i manage to get the full array of the displayed categories this way, so that's a progress. But what i really need is to be notified of which category is on screen individually using the @HostListener. What i'm doing wrong and what is the best way to achieve that?